# Создать синоним метки bitrix/битрикс

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Предлагаю создать синоним для меток [bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitrix) и [битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81), только вот не понимаю, который должен быть основным. Вроде, вариант с написанием кириллицей предпочтительнее?

Comment: Может быть вы напишите вики-описание для метки?

Comment: @Nofate готово.

Answer (score 3):

К метке [битрикс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81) добавлены синонимы [bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitrix) и [1c-bitrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/1c-bitrix).

Comment: Упустил 1c-bitrix. Раз он есть, давайте лучше сделам основной меткой "1с-битрикс" (именно так называется продукт, см. http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/), а остальные три - алиасами для неё.

Comment: [tag:битрикс] я выбрал основной меткой исходя из статистики использования. Метку *1с-битрикс* еще никто не предлагал, так что я не уверен в ее целесообразности.

Comment: Продукт изначально назывался "битрикс". Сколько бы раз не перекупят фирму и не понадобавляют своих префиксов в название из маркетинговых соображений -- всё равно имеет смысл базовым сделать название именно "битрикс".