# Что делать, если найден синоним метки, но не хватает репутации? Метка "template"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Нашёл несколько [подобных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/236/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-bitrix-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81) вопросов здесь.

Как я понял это нормально предлагать синонимы меток в виде вопроса на мете.

1. Предлагаю добавить следующие синонимы:

   [шаблон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd); [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b).

   Для метки [template](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template).
2. А так же объединить метки [шаблонизатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80); [шаблонизаторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b).

Comment: модераторы могут волевым решением применять синонимы

Comment: Нужно, мне кажется, как-то отделить шаблоны в языках программирования с шаблонным метапрограммированием (c++) от шаблонизаторов (текстовых препроцессоров)

Comment: @Nofate, да, я шаблонизаторы вынес отдельным предложением.

Comment: похожий вопрос, кстати: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2729/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: [Вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3409/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b8-template) по теме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв!

Как я понял, в обсуждении в чате было принято решение оставить [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b) как многопрофильное понятие. Для остальных меток были назначены синонимы.